# Import data from a CSV file into excel from a specific location

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to put together a VBA code to import data from a CSV file stored in a specific location and paste the data in my desired worksheet. What I have done is I simply recorded a macro where I have stored the file location in a string variable named 'path' and used this variable to specify the file location. But after executing the code, its showing an error saying that "Excel can not find the text file to refresh this external data range". Below is provided the code:
Advanced thanks for your help.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim path As String
    path = InputBox("Provide the location of the file")

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;path.csv" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "AO2576.log.0240021"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. With the modified code, I can import the data from the location. But what I am trying to do is, I'll specify the location of the file and the macro should open the file from that location and import the data in the active(or specified worksheet) worksheet. The location will vary each time but there is always one csv file in that location. My target is to run the macro, user will specify the file location & the rest of the job will be done by the macro. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You should open the file with a file dialog and set accordingly the QueryTable.

```
Dim path: path = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv")
If path = False Then Exit Sub 
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & path, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    ...
End With
```

Notice that `"TEXT;path.csv"` is a hardcoded string, it is not set from the file's name just selected by user. `"TEXT;" & path` is the way to go.